# Can I sync my Ubuntu system like chromeOS?

Tags: sync

I make various changes to my settings in Ubuntu. I install a few apps and set my personal preferences. How can I sync the same settings to a different PC where I use Ubuntu. Is there a *sync settings* utility available to restore apps and settings?

I want to store all this data in the cloud somewhere, so that I can restore my all apps and settings with a click/command line.